# Component naming conventions

Tags: pcb, components, standard

Some very common parts have standard acronyms on schematics: resistors are usually named R#, capacitors C#, and integrated circuits U#.

Is there a typical standard for these names? If I want my BOM to look "normal" at the end of my design (ie: without any symbols that are weird + unfamiliar to other people looking at it), what should I do?

Comment: Why not provide a list of the types of components that you want to use and let list members chime in with the appropriate prefixes.  You already have 3 good choices.

Comment: FWIW - I always prefer single letter prefixes.  When I first started in electronics, chips had the prefix of "IC".  I greatly prefer the prefix "U" instead and made that change many years ago.

Comment: I found this in the Related sidebar: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/10327/49251

Not sure why I couldn't find it earlier...

Comment: @Dwayne: I think I would rather have a more generic list (like the one I linked) than one that's specific to my project. I also like the look of single-letter prefixes :)

Answer (score 7):

B = battery

C = Capacitor

D = Diode (including LED)

F = Fuse

H = Header connector

J = connector

K = relay

L = inductor

M = Motor

N = Network (containing multiple passive components - usually resistors or capacitors)

Q = transistor

P = Potentiometer (some people use this, I don't)

R = Resistor

S = Switch

T = transformer

TP = Test Point

U = chip or integrated circuit

V = varistor / MOV

X = crystal

BR = Bridge Rectifier

Anyone who wants to add to this list, please feel free to do so.

Comment: How in the world did anyone get from "relay" to "K"?

Comment: Back in the stony ages, R-esistors happened before relays, so that reference designator was already taken, and grandfathered in, when relays came along.  Probably, then, the list was populated with J-ack being the last entry, so the next one, "K", was assigned to relays.

Comment: Other common variants: M = MOSFET, J = jack (connector) and P = plug (connector).

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard for this. Originally it was IEEE 200-1975, and had an ANSI standard associated with it. (ANSI Y32.16-1975) IEEE maintained it up through the 90s, then dropped support. Recently, ASME has taken up the standard. (ASME Y14.44-2008) You would have to pay to access the standard, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) has a fairly complete list. In reality, no one follows the standard exactly, but as long as what you're using is close and makes sense, very few people will question it.