# Electrical schematics component ID's

Tags: schematics, power-engineering, standard, code

Is there a list of standard ID codes used for components on a schematic drawing that anyone can point to?

e.g.

K = Contactor
S = Switch
Y = Solenoid
X = Terminal strip

etc.

Any list would be good, although if there is anything relating to Australian Standards that would be great.

Comment: Related http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10327/standard-nomenclature-for-component-types but not dupe as this is specific to Aussie standards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are from AS 3702, *Item Designation in Electrotechnology*. This is equivalent to IEC 60750.

There is a three-page long table of "Item" vs. "Letter Code" including -

```
Contactor                        K
Relay                            K
Switching devices for control    S
Switching devices for power      Q
Solenoid                         Y
Terminal                         X
```

---

For countries following American practice, the [Reference Designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) come from IEEE 315-1975 and IEEE 200-1795. These are different to the AS / IEC letter codes.

Comment: Why is everything crossed out ?

Comment: @efox29 Because I made two attempts at answering the question. The first attempt was wrong (for Australian context.)

Comment: Then perhaps remove (not cross out) anything that is no relevant to the question. I see that @passerby linked to a question which has similar content to the crossed out content of this answer.

Comment: @efox29: I just edited.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip: IEC 60750 appears to have been superceded by IEC 81346-1 Ed. 1.0. Would you agree?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, it appears to have been superceded as of... about two weeks ago. I haven't read IEC 81346 yet.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip: Cool, I like to be up to date :) Do you know of a link to view it (or even AS 3702,) or is the only way to purchase a download?

Comment: @Andy, I have my copy through my company's subscription to SAI Global. I don't believe you'll find a copy on the open Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Although a year later, I stumbled across this and then found some guidelines which I am adapting to my needs, so thought I might share my findings.

The ISO/IEC 81346 one letter codes are [available online](http://81346.com/english/?page_id=42). There is also a introductory video explaining the Reference Designator System they work on for the "common language" attempt for systems. Here is a compiled/merged list of the one Letter codes from their  [current edition 2016](http://81346.com/english/?page_id=42) and [2017 draft](http://81346.com/english/?page_id=590).

- A: (*multi_function*) Two or more purposes or tasks
- B: (*sense*) picking up information and providing a representation
- C: (*store*) storing for subsequent retrieval
- E: (*emit*) emitting
- F: (*protect*) protecting against the effects of dangerous or undesirable conditions
- G: (*generate*) providing a controllable flow
- H: (*process* matter) treating matter
- K: (*process* information) treating input signals and providing an appropriate output
- M: (*drive*) providing mechanical movement or force
- N: (*cover*) enclosing partly or fully another object
- P: (*present*) providing perceptible information
- Q: (*control*) controlling access or flow
- R: (*restrict*) restricting or stabilising
- S: (*interact*) detecting a manual action and providing an appropriate response
- T: (*transform*) transforming
- U: (*hold*) structural positioning of other objects
- W: (*guide*) leading from one place to another
- X: (*interface*) interfacing an object

Taking as reference examples Li-aung Yips' answer, I would interpret to use the following codes.

- Contactor : Q
- Relay : K
- Switching devices for control

  - Automatic : K
  - Manual : S
- Switching devices for power : Q
- Solenoid : QM ?
- Terminal : X

Comment: I am also unsure of the designator for a solenoid coil, based on the new 81346-2 2017 standard. What would a 1 letter code be? "Y" doesn't seem to be a defined class so should it be "M"? Also, how would you reference a PLC with a one letter code?

Comment: @Andy For the ***Solenoid*** case it would depend on its specific purpose/functionality within the design. Without knowing that and needing to be limited to one letter I would use **M** as you are providing a mechanical force.
 For the ***PLC*** (Programmable Logic Controller), depending on the complexity of the task the PLC is doing, I would use either **K** (less complex) or **A** (more complex).

Comment: 'A' makes sense, but it doesn't seem to be defined as a class in the 81356-2 2017 edition as far as I can tell http://81346.com/english/about-81346/about-81346-2-2016-edition/

Comment: Although an [old post, from 2009, it is an interesting one](http://myelectrical.com/notes/entryid/24/iec-reference-designations#myID1310038) where the composition of letters in reference deisgnators for Function, Product, Location of objects is explained and several standards are referenced.