# What component is labeled "SI" on a PCB silkscreen?

Tags: pcb

What component is labeled SI (SI1, SI2, etc) on a PCB? By the way, what kind of capacitor is C7? (The one on the right of the "SI" component, assuming its a capacitor).

EDIT: The PCB is a combined boiler control board (Roca Victoria 20/20T) manufactured in Spain. The attached picture shows the components surrounding the spark igniter, whose transformer is the grey plastic box on the right.

The complete marking is "6W" "R600" "95" "0029". Measured with a leg detached from the PCB, it has no continuity (Tester displays "Open Loop") in both ways. "R600" suggests a 600-ohm resistor, but it's not. I tested the PCB operation with the component removed, and the spark igniter stops working, so it appears to be OK.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Context often helps. Please edit your question to explain what the circuit is supposed to do. (It looks like a small SMPS.) Country of design may help too.

Comment: Need to see the markings on the component

Comment: Could SI stand for "spark igniter"? (Not sure why it would apply to a small on-board component though)

Comment: It's curious that the board was designed with the possibility of an SMD as an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like a [SIDAC.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIAC)

The small transformer and Q1 may generate several hundered volts which accumulates in one of the capacitors, when the SIDAC threshold is reached it begins conducting strongly  dumping a pulse from the capacitor into the ignitor transformer.

Comment: Excellent. I'd never heard of them. Littlefuse has a load of them. https://www.littelfuse.com/products/power-semiconductors/discrete-thyristors/sidac.aspx.

Comment: Don't the creepages look alarmingly narrow for a 600V working voltage, though?

Comment: 600v is probbly wrong, they don't seem to make SIDACs for that voltage. 60 to 400 seems  common. (deleted 600V)

Comment: Thank you! You never stop learning new things. Next thing for me is to get a new SIDAC, and test if it works replacing the one placed in the PCB. That would be the definitive answer. By the way, any ideas regarding the type of C7?

Comment: a working sidac will measure as open circuit unless you hit wit with more voltage than a normal multimeter makes. for C7 the picture seems blurry and what does C7 look like from the ends, C7 could be damaged.

Comment: I'll post better pictures of C7 tonight ...

Comment: You should do that as a separate question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The SI component designation is not listed in Wikipedia's [Reference designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) and not listed in this site's [Standard nomenclature for component types](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10327/standard-nomenclature-for-component-types). It's either non-standard or means something in Spanish.

[image]

*Figure 1. Forensic analysis.*

The component is marked '0029'. If you detach one leg and bend the component up you may be able to read the rest of the markings. Update the question and we'll take it from there.

Comment: That's correct, I checked the IEEE Std 315-1975 document and Wikipedia before posting, though with no luck. I'll post the exact marking later when I'm back at home.

Comment: I'm not sure this really qualifies as an answer....?

Answer (score 0):

use this information. its a sidac.

https://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/sidac.htm

Comment: Amir Rashedi - Welcome :-) This is quite short for an answer here. It would help if you can [Edit] your answer and add details explaining why you believe this is the correct answer. Notice that the question already has an [accepted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/448686/101852), which gives some evidence for the identification as a SIDAC. If you only wanted to add that link as an extra source of information, then I can convert your answer to be a comment on that accepted answer (as you cannot write comments yourself yet). Thanks.